# How to change ruby code using Javascript injections?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to change the params[:offset] parameter using my pagination (Numbers 1,2,3,4,5). With every Number the :offset should increase/decrease by 10 so that I get the next 10 search results:

```
"<% text_field_tag :offset, params[:offset] || 0 %>"
```

To do this I wrote this Javascript code:

search.js

```
var zero = 0;
var offset = "<% text_field_tag :offset, params[:offset] || " + zero + " %>";

document.getElementById("skip").innerHTML = offset;

function changeoffset1() {
    var a = document.getElementById('first').text;

    var b = parseInt(a);

    zero = (b - 1) * 10;

    var offset = "\<\% text_field_tag :offset, params[:offset] || " + zero +        " %>";

    document.getElementById("skip").innerHTML = offset;

}  

function changeoffset2() {  
   var c = document.getElementById('second').text;

   var d = parseInt(c);

   zero = (d - 1) * 10;  

   var offset = "\<\% text_field_tag :offset, params[:offset] || " + zero +   " %>";

   document.getElementById("skip").innerHTML = offset;

}
....
```

And in the view I added this div:

```
"<div id="skip"><br> </div>"
```

Instead of being able to use my params hash within the code the text is show on my page as if the injected <% ruby code %> is no ruby code any more but text only.

How can I inject some ruby code that is changed by clicking a pagination link ?

Or how could I change my params value otherwise clicking on pagination links?

Comment: You'll need to fix the formatting. Your question is illegible right now.

Comment: Google Ruby Metaprogramming

Comment: Ruby runs first, *then* JavaScript, and there's no third pass where Ruby runs again. The way to fix this is to figure out what you're trying to do in terms of order of operations. `text_field_tag` generates a literal chunk of HTML. How that's useful in your JavaScript I don't know. Try using something like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) if you want to have client-side templates.

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Why do you think you need to change the Ruby code instead of passing parameter between the client and the server? Do you try to build some kind of pagination?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't.

Ruby code is executed at the server.

Page JavaScript is executed by the client (webbrowser).

By time JavaScript executes, it's already been parsed by the Ruby interpreter.

Comment: Then how can I change my params?

Comment: <% text_field_tag :offset, params[:offset] || 0 %> instead of 0 I need 10 after clicking my pagination link?